# How to insert the percentage sign into a local URL

Tags: html, hyperlink

Good day

I wanted to have a general URL to access the Desktop of the local machine for every local user, but when I put this link into the shared HTML page:

```
href="file://%userprofile%\Desktop"
```

the URL that appears on the browser is:

```
file://%25userprofile%25\Desktop
```

How to remove that '25' so every local user can access his/her Desktop?

Thank you very much

Comment: I've tried adding the HTML character code for '%' but the '25' is still appearing on the browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%` is a special character on the URL - it is used to [encode special characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), giving their HEX ASCII value as result.

Hence, in order to pass a `%` on the URL, you need to encode it - this results in `%25` - the browser is doing the right think and you don't need to do anything.

I am not sure the browser can interpret local environment variables, by the way - it may also not have direct access to the user desktop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I'm afraid I have to disagree. When I insert `file://%userprofile%\Desktop` directly on the browser URL field (Internet Explorer) it opens my Desktop folder automatically

Comment: @joao_pimentel - IE is closely bound to the Windows desktop. Try it in any other browser.

Comment: The brwoser is interpreting '%25' and when I embed that URL on a HTML page, it does not open that folder (it should open with IE)

Comment: But to this application I'm developping, just IE applies

Answer (score 1):

Use %25 without space. it will show the percent symbol in the url.